# Extension method for logging dotnet core webapi how do I get the calling projects/assembly name?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, shared-libraries, serilog, asp.net-core-logging

This is the extension method

```
public static IApplicationBuilder UseLoggerConfig(this IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    //add serilog https://github.com/serilog/serilog-extensions-logging
    // https://github.com/serilog/serilog-extensions-logging/blob/dev/samples/Sample/Program.cs
    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    .WriteTo.File("log.txt", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)
    .CreateLogger();

    var startTime = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;

    Log.Logger.Information("Started at {StartTime} and 0x{Hello:X} is hex of 42", startTime, 42);

    return app;
}
```

and we can use this in `Startup` like so

```
app.UseLoggerConfig();
```

I Would like to save the logs on `\\%windir%\log\callingAppName\logfile.log`.

Any ideas how we could do this ?

Comment: I am thinking you could check the environment for information like that. Given that this is meant to be shared, it should be explicitly injected from where it is being used/called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am thinking you could check the [hosting environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.ihostingenvironment?view=aspnetcore-2.0) for information like that.

> [`IHostingEnvironment.ApplicationName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.ihostingenvironment.applicationname?view=aspnetcore-2.0#Definition)
>
> Gets or sets the name of the application. **This property is automatically set by the host to the assembly containing the application entry point**.

*emphasis mine*

Given that this is meant to be shared, it should be explicitly injected from where it is being used/called. ie the web hosting environment the application is running in.

```
public static IApplicationBuilder UseLoggerConfig(this IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) {

    var callingAppName = env.ApplicationName;

    var path = $"{callingAppName}/logfile.log";

    //add serilog https://github.com/serilog/serilog-extensions-logging
    // https://github.com/serilog/serilog-extensions-logging/blob/dev/samples/Sample/Program.cs
    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    .WriteTo.File(path, rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)
    .CreateLogger();

    var startTime = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;

    Log.Logger.Information("Started at {StartTime} and 0x{Hello:X} is hex of 42", startTime, 42);

    return app;
}
```

and we can use this in `Startup` like so

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) {

    //...code removed for brevity

    app.UseLoggerConfig(env);
}
```

This would also allow for the changing of logging location based environment type like development, staging, production,  etc.

```
public static IApplicationBuilder UseLoggerConfig(this IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) {

    var callingAppName = env.ApplicationName;

    var path = $"{callingAppName}/logfile.log";
    if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
        // In Development logging path
    } else {
        // In Staging/Production logging path
    }

    //add serilog https://github.com/serilog/serilog-extensions-logging
    // https://github.com/serilog/serilog-extensions-logging/blob/dev/samples/Sample/Program.cs
    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    .WriteTo.File(path, rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)
    .CreateLogger();

    var startTime = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;

    Log.Logger.Information("Started at {StartTime} and 0x{Hello:X} is hex of 42", startTime, 42);

    return app;
}
```